# Method prefixes in Go

Tags: go

In go, there's a "prefix" that you can put on a function. How is this useful? What are the use cases for this?

Example:

```
type a struct {
    Thing string
}

func (something a) b() {
    fmt.Println(something.Thing)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Programming is communication: you are communicating to the machine what it should do, and communicating to other programmers (including your future self). Many higher-level programming constructs serve the purpose of making code more expressive--that is, more clearly stating the programmer's intent.

Go's function receivers are like the "self" object in more traditional object-oriented languages. It's a way of grouping a set of functions together and saying "these methods exist primarily to operate on objects of this type", rather than just being general utility methods that happen to take an argument of that type. In other words, they exist to describe the behavior of the abstract object whose state is described by the structure.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the function is *attached* to the struct, in this case, so that you can do `a.b()` somewhere else.

Comment: What are the use cases, though?

Comment: @innectic you can call it with `a.b()`